# How to rename "browse" button in Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I can rename it in a aspx File using an extra Button and a Javascript method that puts the button in front of the FileUpload.

but how to achive the same in a MVC View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file" })
```

Comment: You can use standard HTML syntax in a razor view.  Just ensure your id and name attrbutes are the same as your model properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of Bootstrap FileStyle plugin